# Why cannot a suitable driver be found for jdbc:derby:derbyDB

Tags: java, derby, javadb

I have recently installed jdk and jre on a Windows 10 machine and cannot get any of the projects that I had on my old machine to work. The main difficulty is that jdk1.8.0_60 does not include JavaDB/Derby, ie, there is no 'db' directory installed with the release, whereas jdk1.7.0_ 79 did have a db folder packaged along with the usual bin, include and lib directories. The package also contains a sample database called derbyDb. To rectify this I downloaded derby from the Apache website and then verified both derby and java in a cmd shell acordingly:

Checked the path to derby:

```
>C:\Users\Administrator>echo %DERBY_HOME%
(Output) C:\Apache\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin
```

Check the path to JDK:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>echo %JAVA_HOME%
(Output) C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
```

Add the DERBY_HOME/bin directory to the PATH environment variable and check through System > Environment variables dialog.  Verified the path includes:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin
```

Checked the path set to point to class libraries:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>echo %CLASSPATH%
(output) .;C:\Apache\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin\lib;
```

As none of my database projects that I have copied over from my old windows 8.1 machine work, I tried to figure what was happening by running the demo app `SimpleApp.java` from the `C:\Apache\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin\demo\programs\simple` download as folllows:

In cmd shell changed dir to the home of SimpleApp and tried to run the app:

```
C:\Apache\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin\demo\programs\simple>java SimpleApp
```

Output:

```
SimpleApp starting in embedded mode

----- SQLException -----
  SQL State:  08001
  Error Code: 0
  Message:    No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:derbyDB;create=true
 SimpleApp finished
```

I simply dont understand what is happening or where to begin troubleshooting this issue and really need some assistance.  This is the SimpleApp source:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;


/**
 * <p>
 * This sample program is a minimal Java application showing JDBC access to a
 * Derby database.</p>
 * <p>
 * Instructions for how to run this program are
 * given in <A HREF=example.html>example.html</A>, by default located in the
 * same directory as this source file ($DERBY_HOME/demo/programs/simple    /).</p>
 * <p>
 * Derby applications can run against Derby running in an embedded
 * or a client/server framework.</p>
 * <p>
 * When Derby runs in an embedded framework, the JDBC application and Derby
 * run in the same Java Virtual Machine (JVM). The application
 * starts up the Derby engine.</p>
 * <p>
 * When Derby runs in a client/server framework, the application runs in a
 * different JVM from Derby. The connectivity framework (in this case the     Derby
 * Network Server) provides network connections. The client driver is loaded
 * automatically.</p>
 */
public class SimpleApp
{
    /* the default framework is embedded */
    private String framework = "embedded";
    private String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";

    /**
     * <p>
     * Starts the demo by creating a new instance of this class and running
     * the <code>go()</code> method.</p>
     * <p>
     * When you run this application, you may give one of the following
     * arguments:
     *  <ul>
          <li><code>embedded</code> - default, if none specified. Will use
     *        Derby's embedded driver. This driver is included in the derby.jar
     *        file.</li>
     *    <li><code>derbyclient</code> - will use the Derby client driver to
     *        access the Derby Network Server. This driver is included in the
     *        derbyclient.jar file.</li>
     *  </ul>
     * <p>
     * When you are using a client/server framework, the network server must
     * already be running when trying to obtain client connections to Derby.
     * This demo program will will try to connect to a network server on this
     * host (the localhost), see the <code>protocol</code> instance variable.
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * When running this demo, you must include the correct driver in the
     * classpath of the JVM. See <a href="example.html">example.html</a> for
     * details.
     * </p>
     * @param args This program accepts one optional argument specifying which
     *        connection framework (JDBC driver) to use (see above). The default
     *        is to use the embedded JDBC driver.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new SimpleApp().go(args);
        System.out.println("SimpleApp finished");
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Starts the actual demo activities. This includes creating a database by
     * making a connection to Derby (automatically loading the driver),
     * creating a table in the database, and inserting, updating and retrieving
     * some data. Some of the retrieved data is then verified (compared) against
     * the expected results. Finally, the table is deleted and, if the embedded
     * framework is used, the database is shut down.</p>
     * <p>
    * Generally, when using a client/server framework, other clients may be
     * (or want to be) connected to the database, so you should be careful about
     * doing shutdown unless you know that no one else needs to access the
     * database until it is rebooted. That is why this demo will not shut down
     * the database unless it is running Derby embedded.</p>
     *
     * @param args - Optional argument specifying which framework or JDBC driver
     *        to use to connect to Derby. Default is the embedded framework,
     *        see the <code>main()</code> method for details.
     * @see #main(String[])
     */
    void go(String[] args)
    {
        /* parse the arguments to determine which framework is desired*/
        parseArguments(args);

        System.out.println("SimpleApp starting in " + framework + " mode");

        /* We will be using Statement and PreparedStatement objects for
         * executing SQL. These objects, as well as Connections and ResultSets,
          * are resources that should be released explicitly after use, hence
         * the try-catch-finally pattern used below.
         * We are storing the Statement and Prepared statement object references
         * in an array list for convenience.
         */
        Connection conn = null;
        ArrayList<Statement> statements = new ArrayList<Statement>(); // list of Statements, PreparedStatements
        PreparedStatement psInsert;
        PreparedStatement psUpdate;
        Statement s;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try
        {
            Properties props = new Properties(); // connection properties
            // providing a user name and password is optional in the embedded
            // and derbyclient frameworks
            props.put("user", "user1");
            props.put("password", "user1");

            /* By default, the schema APP will be used when no username is
             * provided.
             * Otherwise, the schema name is the same as the user name (in this
             * case "user1" or USER1.)
             *
             * Note that user authentication is off by default, meaning that any
             * user can connect to your database using any password. To enable
             * authentication, see the Derby Developer's Guide.
             */

            String dbName = "derbyDB"; // the name of the database

            /*
             * This connection specifies create=true in the connection URL to
             * cause the database to be created when connecting for the first
             * time. To remove the database, remove the directory derbyDB (the
             * same as the database name) and its contents.
             *
             * The directory derbyDB will be created under the directory that
             * the system property derby.system.home points to, or the current
             * directory (user.dir) if derby.system.home is not set.
             */
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol + dbName
                    + ";create=true", props);

            System.out.println("Connected to and created database " + dbName);

            // We want to control transactions manually. Autocommit is on by
            // default in JDBC.
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            /* Creating a statement object that we can use for running various
             * SQL statements commands against the database.*/
            s = conn.createStatement();
            statements.add(s);

            // We create a table...
            s.execute("create table location(num int, addr varchar(40))");
            System.out.println("Created table location");

            // and add a few rows...

            /* It is recommended to use PreparedStatements when you are
             * repeating execution of an SQL statement. PreparedStatements also
             * allows you to parameterize variables. By using PreparedStatements
             * you may increase performance (because the Derby engine does not
             * have to recompile the SQL statement each time it is executed) and
             * improve security (because of Java type checking).
             */
            // parameter 1 is num (int), parameter 2 is addr (varchar)
            psInsert = conn.prepareStatement(
                        "insert into location values (?, ?)");
            statements.add(psInsert);

            psInsert.setInt(1, 1956);
            psInsert.setString(2, "Webster St.");
            psInsert.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Inserted 1956 Webster");

            psInsert.setInt(1, 1910);
            psInsert.setString(2, "Union St.");
            psInsert.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Inserted 1910 Union");

            // Let's update some rows as well...

            // parameter 1 and 3 are num (int), parameter 2 is addr (varchar)
            psUpdate = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "update location set num=?, addr=? where num=?");
            statements.add(psUpdate);

            psUpdate.setInt(1, 180);
            psUpdate.setString(2, "Grand Ave.");
            psUpdate.setInt(3, 1956);
            psUpdate.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Updated 1956 Webster to 180 Grand");

            psUpdate.setInt(1, 300);
            psUpdate.setString(2, "Lakeshore Ave.");
            psUpdate.setInt(3, 180);
            psUpdate.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Updated 180 Grand to 300 Lakeshore");


            /*
               We select the rows and verify the results.
             */
            rs = s.executeQuery(
                    "SELECT num, addr FROM location ORDER BY num");

            /* we expect the first returned column to be an integer (num),
             * and second to be a String (addr). Rows are sorted by street
             * number (num).
             *
             * Normally, it is best to use a pattern of
             *  while(rs.next()) {
             *    // do something with the result set
             *  }
             * to process all returned rows, but we are only expecting two rows
             * this time, and want the verification code to be easy to
             * comprehend, so we use a different pattern.
             */

            int number; // street number retrieved from the database
            boolean failure = false;
            if (!rs.next())
            {
                failure = true;
                reportFailure("No rows in ResultSet");
            }

            if ((number = rs.getInt(1)) != 300)
            {
                failure = true;
                reportFailure(
                        "Wrong row returned, expected num=300, got " + number);
            }

            if (!rs.next())
            {
                failure = true;
                reportFailure("Too few rows");
            }

            if ((number = rs.getInt(1)) != 1910)
            {
                failure = true;
                reportFailure(
                        "Wrong row returned, expected num=1910, got " + number);
            }

            if (rs.next())
            {
                failure = true;
                reportFailure("Too many rows");
            }

            if (!failure) {
                System.out.println("Verified the rows");
            }

            // delete the table
            s.execute("drop table location");
            System.out.println("Dropped table location");

            /*
               We commit the transaction. Any changes will be persisted to
               the database now.
             */
            conn.commit();
            System.out.println("Committed the transaction");

            /*
             * In embedded mode, an application should shut down the database.
             * If the application fails to shut down the database,
             * Derby will not perform a checkpoint when the JVM shuts down.
             * This means that it will take longer to boot (connect to) the
             * database the next time, because Derby needs to perform a recovery
             * operation.
             *
             * It is also possible to shut down the Derby system/engine, which
             * automatically shuts down all booted databases.
             *
             * Explicitly shutting down the database or the Derby engine with
             * the connection URL is preferred. This style of shutdown will
             * always throw an SQLException.
             *
             * Not shutting down when in a client environment, see method
             * Javadoc.
             */

            if (framework.equals("embedded"))
            {
                try
                {
                    // the shutdown=true attribute shuts down Derby
                    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");

                    // To shut down a specific database only, but keep the
                    // engine running (for example for connecting to other
                    // databases), specify a database in the connection URL:
                    //DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:" + dbName + ";shutdown=true");
                }
                catch (SQLException se)
                {
                    if (( (se.getErrorCode() == 50000)
                            && ("XJ015".equals(se.getSQLState()) ))) {
                        // we got the expected exception
                        System.out.println("Derby shut down normally");
                        // Note that for single database shutdown, the expected
                        // SQL state is "08006", and the error code is 45000.
                    } else {
                        // if the error code or SQLState is different, we have
                        // an unexpected exception (shutdown failed)
                        System.err.println("Derby did not shut down normally");
                        printSQLException(se);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            printSQLException(sqle);
        } finally {
            // release all open resources to avoid unnecessary memory usage

            // ResultSet
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                    rs = null;
                }
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                printSQLException(sqle);
            }

            // Statements and PreparedStatements
            int i = 0;
            while (!statements.isEmpty()) {
                // PreparedStatement extend Statement
                Statement st = (Statement)statements.remove(i);
                try {
                    if (st != null) {
                        st.close();
                        st = null;
                    }
                } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                    printSQLException(sqle);
                }
            }

            //Connection
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                    conn = null;
                }
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            printSQLException(sqle);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reports a data verification failure to System.err with the given message.
     *
     * @param message A message describing what failed.
     */
    private void reportFailure(String message) {
        System.err.println("\nData verification failed:");
        System.err.println('\t' + message);
    }

    /**
     * Prints details of an SQLException chain to <code>System.err</code>.
     * Details included are SQL State, Error code, Exception message.
     *
     * @param e the SQLException from which to print details.
     */
    public static void printSQLException(SQLException e)
    {
        // Unwraps the entire exception chain to unveil the real cause of the
        // Exception.
        while (e != null)
        {
            System.err.println("\n----- SQLException -----");
            System.err.println("  SQL State:  " + e.getSQLState());
            System.err.println("  Error Code: " + e.getErrorCode());
            System.err.println("  Message:    " + e.getMessage());
            // for stack traces, refer to derby.log or uncomment this:
            //e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            e = e.getNextException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parses the arguments given and sets the values of this class's instance
     * variables accordingly - that is, which framework to use, the name of the
     * JDBC driver class, and which connection protocol to use. The
     * protocol should be used as part of the JDBC URL when connecting to Derby.
     * <p>
     * If the argument is "embedded" or invalid, this method will not change
     * anything, meaning that the default values will be used.</p>
     * <p>
     * @param args JDBC connection framework, either "embedded" or "derbyclient".
     * Only the first argument will be considered, the rest will be ignored.
       */
    private void parseArguments(String[] args)
    {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("derbyclient"))
            {
                framework = "derbyclient";
                protocol = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try javac -classpath "path/to/derby.jar" path/to/SimpleApp.java to compile with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Checked the path set to point to class libraries:

C:\Users\Administrator>echo %CLASSPATH%
(output) .;C:\Apache\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin\lib;
```

This doesn't actually work the way you think it does. Naming the directory does **not** include all the jar files in the directory.

You need to name each jar file in your classpath; alternatively, what I do is to use the 'derbyrun.jar' jar file, which is an umbrella jar which automatically includes all the other Derby jar files.

So set your `CLASSPATH` to `C:\Apache\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin\lib\derbyrun.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Try somethink like this

```
     String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost/webdb";
     Properties properties = new Properties();
     properties.put("create", "true");
     properties.put("user", "tom");
     properties.put("password", "secret");

     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, properties);



     String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost/webdb;create=true";
     String user = "tom";
     String password = "secret";
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, password);


     public class JdbcDerbyConnection {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
        // connect method #1 - embedded driver
        String dbURL1 = "jdbc:derby:codejava/webdb1;create=true";
        Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL1);
        if (conn1 != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to database #1");
        }

        // connect method #2 - network client driver
        String dbURL2 = "jdbc:derby://localhost/webdb2;create=true";
        String user = "tom";
        String password = "secret";
        Connection conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL2, user, password);
        if (conn2 != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to database #2");
        }

        // connect method #3 - network client driver
        String dbURL3 = "jdbc:derby://localhost/webdb3";
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("create", "true");
        properties.put("user", "tom");
        properties.put("password", "secret");

        Connection conn3 = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL3, properties);
        if (conn3 != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to database #3");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```